# How do I configure QT5 without Xlib

Tags: c++, linux, qt, framebuffer

I am trying to configure (and build) QT5 static. I want it to draw to the framebuffer and use webkit. I searched the docs but I didn't find anything on how I can do this without X. Does anyone know a way of doing this ?

Comment: Can you use Wayland?

Comment: It should just be the plain framebuffer

Comment: Why can't you use X11 and/or a shared library? You need a commercial license to sell a statically-linked Qt application; then, Qt will give you some support

Comment: I am not going to sell anything ^^ There is no X-server on my target...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Building Qt statically is totally orthogonal to the platform selection.** Depending on your target device, you can choose between using Wayland, EGLFS, LinuxFB/DirectFB, etc.

Just be sure when you run `configure` that the actual plugin you're interested in gets compiled. In other words, check `configure`'s final output (or read the `config.summary` file generated). If the platform is not there, run `configure -v` and try to see what's missing (headers, libs, ...).

You can then make any application use a given plugin by simply starting the application and passing the argument `-platform eglfs|wayland|...` (or by setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` environment variable; or you can make it the default by mangling with the *device mkspecs*). [More info here.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html)

When it actually comes to static linking: this multi-platform support is implemented via plugins. A statically linked application won't have plugin loading available, so you must actually link the platform plugin into the application itself by adding something like

```
QTPLUGIN.platforms = eglfs
```

into your `.pro` file. [More info here.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins)

Comment: So would : `./configure -platform linuxfb` be enough to use (only) the framebuffer ?

Comment: It's not a `configure` argument, it's a runtime argument for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the "*minimal*" plugin and blit it into the framebuffer (something similar to the discussion at http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-April/021160.html). However, ask your Platform vendor - check if "eglfs with fb" is a supported option.

However be aware that things like Cursor, overlays, rotation, vsync handling, GPU acceleration, may not be fully supported in these non-mainstream options on Linux.

Comment: What is this minimal plugin that you're talking about ?

Comment: Its a platform plugin for rendering the output to a raw file (filled with pixels representing the screen). Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488072/what-is-the-use-of-various-qt-platform-plugins. Refer to http://gpupowered.org/node/20 for (slightly outdated) build steps of minimal plugin for an ARM platform (Beagle). Note that this plugin is built in the default configuration itself. You use it as ./yourqt5_app -platform minimal